# Show as tab option/addon for firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

In chrome when a popup window opens, we have an option to make it as a tab and hence we could move/dock it to the main chrome browser window.

I could not find a similar **Show as tab** option for firefox? Is there atleast an addon available for the same? I am not able to find one.

Thanks.

Comment: There's an option to "open new windows in a new tab instead", which is handy. Other than that, does the new windows have the normal tab headers? If so, you can probably just drag the tab header from the new window to the old one to move it over (works with non-popped up windows).

Comment: **open new windows in a new tab instead** does not always help. and, the new windows do not have normal tab headers. :(

Comment: @bdhar How about if you tick the "always show tab bar" option as well? Is this a "normal" pop-up, or something more unusual? (PS: what version of Firefox?)

Comment: Yes, It's there checked by default. I am using Firefox 4. Not sure, seems like a normal popup. It has an embedded flash music player in it.

Comment: @bdhar How strange then. Presumably you have got pop-up's disabled? I think that's the default too. In which case we've at least covered the basic options, and it looks like something "odd" may be happening...I'm out of immediate ideas I'm afriad...

Comment: No problem, thanks. Let me keep looking for answers and will post if I get one. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) extension should do exactly what you want. Set the JavaScript & Popup restriction to "Open all popups in tabs".

You can also prevent Firefox from ever opening a second window by enabling "Single Window Mode"

[image]